# Smooth Scroll On Multi Page Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, smooth-scrolling

I've been scouring stack overflow but cannot seem to find a solution. Basically I'm trying to make a smooth scroll effect work across multiple pages. EG the smooth scroll effect is on the websites homepage- Home about contact shop are the navigation link for example, the smooth scroll being about & contact, which reside on the homepage. When Im on the shop page and click on the about & contact links, nothing happens!

The effect works perfect on the homepage, is there any way the below code can be tweaked so that when a user clicks either 'about' or 'contact' whilst on the shop page, it will return to the 'home' page, then scroll to the appropriate link? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
var jump=function(e)
{
   if (e){
       e.preventDefault();
       var target = $(this).attr("href");
   }else{
       var target = location.hash;
   }

   $('html,body').animate(
   {
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
   },2000,function()
   {
       location.hash = target;
   });

}

$('html, body').hide();

$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('a[href^=#]').bind("click", jump);

    if (location.hash){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('html, body').scrollTop(0).show();
            jump();
        }, 0);
    }else{
        $('html, body').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: I think a simple anchor on your link will do the job.

Comment: I have anchors set, e.g <div id="contact"> and it will only scroll to these anchors while im on the home page, but on the shop page it does nothing?

Comment: I've change the navigation link to the full url eg www.mysite.com/#contact - this works from the other page now but the smooth scroll effect doesnt work anymore!?

Comment: That make sense this is another thing do a bit of research on Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work I guess :

```
//This is the function to scroll to your anchor
function scrollToElement(ele) {
    $(window).scrollTop(ele.offset().top).scrollLeft(ele.offset().left);
}

//This is to get the anchor
if(window.location.hash) {
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].href == window.location.hash){
            scrollToElement(window.location.hash);
        }
    }
}
```

You may have to do some arrangement I h'avent tested it but this is the general idea.

Comment: Hmm this doesn't quite work - this is appending the anchor to the current page, eg it's changing www.mywebsite.com/shop/ to www.mywebsite.com/shop/contact, when it should be www.mywebsite.com/contact/ . Thanks for you suggestion anyway